# Quiero tomar literalmente "\n" , pero hace un salto de linea

Tags: python

```py
class Solution:
    def rectanguloEspecial(self,longitud,altura,letra_base,letra_especial):
        n = int(longitud)
        m = int(altura)
        lb = letra_base
        le = letra_especial
        det = abs(n - m)

        for i in range(1, m + 1):
            for j in range(1, n + 1):
                if (i + j) % det == 0:
                    print(le, end="")
                else:
                    print(lb, end="")
            print("", end="\n")
        return ""
print(Solution().rectanguloEspecial(6,4,"O","L"))
#output deseado: LOLOLO\nOLOLOL\nLOLOLO\nOLOLOL
```

Comment: Escapa la diagonal inversa "\\n"

Comment: podrías añadir una explicación de lo que hace tu código?

Comment: `print("", end="\\n")`

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema es fácil, pues simplemente tenemos que *escapar* al carácter, para escapar a un carácter se usa la barra invertida `\`, seguramente la has visto en expresiones regulares para poder tomar en cuenta la `\` de una url. No hay mucha ciencia detrás de esto pues solo hay que poner `\\n` y asi el caracter que este después de `\` sera tomado como literal y se mostrara en el `print()`

```py
...
else:
    print(lb, end="")
print("", end="\\n")
```

Esto sirve para cualquier carácter especial `^`, `/`,`.`,etc. si se le antepone `\` será tomado como un simple string y no como carácter especial.

Answer (score 0):

Imprime la variable como un raw String de la siguiente forma:

```py
print(r'%s'  % Solution().rectanguloEspecial(6,4,"O","L"))
```

NOTA: Me guíe por tu última línea del Python que al parecer ese último print era el el retorno de la funcion pero no te referías a ese.

Comment: eso no va a funcionar :/

Comment: Cambie lo que quieres escribe. Creo que no es lb sino lo que puse , es decir un String que contiene \n? Al menos lo entendí asi

Comment: se quiere obtener `LOLOLO\nOLOLOL\nLOLOLO\nOLOLOL\n` ósea que el `\n` se muestre como cadena

Comment: Me guíe por la última línea del Python

Comment: en mi comentario dije la solución, puedes publicarla, pues yo no considero hacer una respuesta

Comment: Gracias, pero ya que  quede ahí nomás. Yo pensaba que la función retornaba ese String largo pero ese es el resultado de los print dentro  de la función, jeje