# Como hago para eliminar el ultimo salto de linea?

Tags: python

```
class Solution:
    def rectanguloEspecial(self,longitud,altura,letra_base,letra_especial):
        n = int(longitud)
        m = int(altura)
        lb = letra_base
        le = letra_especial
        det = abs(n - m)

        for i in range(0, m):
            for j in range(0, n):
                if (i + j) % det == 0:
                    print(le, end="")
                else:
                    print(lb, end="")
            print("a", end="\n")
        return ""
print(Solution().rectanguloEspecial(6,4,"O","L"))
```

Comment: Esto no es duplicado?

Comment: @AnkiJedi no lo es

Comment: Me parece que sí, acaba de formular una pregunta extremadamente similar que ya fue contestada, si se explicaron bien las dudas en la pregunta anterior no debería de tener problemas con esta nueva y si no, debe esperar a que sea contestada correctamente.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Quiero tomar literalmente "\n" , pero hace un salto de linea](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/459792/quiero-tomar-literalmente-n-pero-hace-un-salto-de-linea)

Comment: la anterior pregunta era para saber como tomar "\n" pero me di cuenta que ese no era el problema. Tengo que imprimir un rectangulo sin el ultimo salto de linea. Por eso volvi con el mismo codigo

Comment: También podrías haber hecho en vez de hacer tanto print guardar en un arreglo la variable y al final imprimes el arreglo. Acabo de ver un respuesta en ese sentido. Deberías tomar ese consejo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes añadir un if para que no imprima ese salto de línea adicional al final del bucle.

`for i in range(0, m)` ejecutará el bucle tantas veces hasta que `i = m -1`. Añade una condicional para que en ese caso no imprima el salto de línea final.

```
class Solution:
    def rectanguloEspecial(self,longitud,altura,letra_base,letra_especial):
        n = int(longitud)
        m = int(altura)
        lb = letra_base
        le = letra_especial
        det = abs(n - m)

        for i in range(0, m):
            for j in range(0, n):
                if (i + j) % det == 0:
                    print(le, end="")
                else:
                    print(lb, end="")
            if i != (m - 1):
                print("a", end="\n")
            else:
                print("a", end ="")            
        return ""

print(Solution().rectanguloEspecial(6,4,"O","L"))
```

Output:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Yo propongo que cambies la forma en como muestras los datos, pues si haces un simple `print()` no estas almacenado los datos y si quieres hacer otra operación en el ciclo `for` se te va a ser muy difícil y al final terminaras cambiando muchas cosas. Mi propuesta es usar una lista como estructura de dato para poder almacenar los resultados, primero habrá una lista global y dentro del primer ciclo `for` habrá una *sub lista* que almacene el resultado de cada iteración de `i`, así:

```py
class Solution:
    def rectanguloEspecial(self,longitud,altura,letra_base,letra_especial):
        n = int(longitud)
        m = int(altura)
        lb = letra_base
        le = letra_especial
        det = abs(n - m)
        lista = [] #aqui se almacenara el resultado total
        for i in range(1, m + 1):
            sub = [] #se almacena el resultado de cada iteracion de i
            for j in range(1, n + 1):
                if (i + j) % det == 0:
                    sub.append(le)#añadimos a la lista
                else:
                    sub.append(lb)#añadimos a la lista
            lista.append("".join(l for l in sub)) #juntamos lo que se creo
        lista = "\\n".join(p for p in lista) #juntamos la lista
        return lista #retornamos la lista

print(Solution().rectanguloEspecial(6,4,"O","L"))
```

Bueno aquí utilizamos una compresión de lista para hacer el proceso mas fácil y rápido. Cada vez que se entra a cualquier bloque del `if/else`, se añade cada letra, en la primera iteración el contenido de `sub` será:

```py
['L', 'O', 'L', 'O', 'L', 'O']
```

Pero nosotros no queremos eso, queremos que el resultado sea:

```py
['LOLOLO']
```

Para eso utilizamos el método `"".join()` que nos sirve para unir los elementos de un iterable. Al mismo tiempo haces un `append()`, es decir cuando el metodo `"".join()` termine que añada lo que genero a la lista, teniendo en la variable `lista` esto:

```py
['LOLOLO']
```

Este proceso se repetirá n veces (las veces que dure el ciclo `for`), en este caso 4 veces, teniendo como resultado `['LOLOLO','OLOLOL','LOLOLO','OLOLOL']` pues ahora lo único que nos falta es unir nuevamente los elementos, pero ahora hay que unirlos mediante un salto de linea escapado `\\n`, para lo cual hacemos uso del mismo metodo `"\\n".join()`. Teniendo como resultado:

```
LOLOLO\nOLOLOL\nLOLOLO\nOLOLOL
```

EL método `.join()` solo une mediante el carácter especificado si hay otro elemento en la lista.

Creo que debí empezar por acá. Si te molestan o no entiendes muy bien las listas, también podemos usar cadenas. es decir en vez de establecer la variable `sub` como una lista lo hacemos como una cadena, y que conforme se cumpla la condición se añada la letra a la cadena, una vez terminada la iteración de `i` se añadirá la cadena a la variable `lista` (que sigue siendo una lista) y así al final solo obtendremos una lista y ya no hará falta recorrerla otra vez.

```py
class Solution:
    def rectanguloEspecial(self,longitud,altura,letra_base,letra_especial):
        n = int(longitud)
        m = int(altura)
        lb = letra_base
        le = letra_especial
        det = abs(n - m)
        lista = []
        for i in range(1, m + 1):
            cadena = "" #creamos una cadena vacia
            for j in range(1, n + 1):
                if (i + j) % det == 0:
                    cadena += le #añadimos la letra a la cadena
                else:
                    cadena += lb #añadimos la letra a la cadena
            #añadimos la cadena formada en la iteracion a la lista
            lista.append(cadena) 
            #la variable lista tiene este aspecto:
            #['LOLOLO', 'OLOLOL', 'LOLOLO', 'OLOLOL']
            #por lo que aun hay que unir sus elementos mediante \n

        #unimos sus elementos
        lista = "\\n".join(p for p in lista)
        return lista #retornamos

print(Solution().rectanguloEspecial(6,4,"O","L"))
```

Algo que se me olvido mencionar en mi anterior respuesta es que al hacer la union mediante `\\n` la lista, internamente, queda de esta forma

```py
#bueno en realidad es una cadena, ya que la unirlo con un string se transforma en string
LOLOLO\\nOLOLOL\\nLOLOLO\\nOLOLOL
```

Solo que al momento de hacer el `print()` este interprete la primera `\` como un escape por lo que la omite.

Answer (score 0):

La última linea en realidad está causada por el `print` que has puesto a `Solution().rectanguloEspecial(6,4,"O","L")` ya que tienes un `return ""` en la función.

Puedes probar a quitarlo y verás que te funciona.

De todas formas, ya que no devuelve nada, puedes quitar también el `return` y alguna cosa más:

```
class Solution:
    def rectanguloEspecial(self,longitud,altura,letra_base,letra_especial):
        n = int(longitud)
        m = int(altura)
        lb = letra_base
        le = letra_especial
        det = abs(n - m)

        for i in range(0, m):
            for j in range(0, n):
                if (i + j) % det == 0:
                    print(le, end="")
                else:
                    print(lb, end="")
            print("a")

print('----------')
Solution().rectanguloEspecial(6,4,"O","L")
print('----------')
```

verás que esto te devuelve ya lo que pides (he puesto `----------` para que veas que no hay saltos extra):

```
----------
LOLOLOa
OLOLOLa
LOLOLOa
OLOLOLa
----------
```